# Query inner records in ElasticSearch Nest C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nested, nest

I have structure like this:

```
public class OuterResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Nested]
    public List<InnerResource> InnerResources { get; set; }
}

public class InnerResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OuterResourceId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Inner records are stored as lists inside outer records. I want to query inner records, giving specified outer resource id and value to filter inner records.

How to do it in C# Nest? Can't figure it out from documentation.

Comment: To be more precise, i want to query them using Elasticsearch query in nest, not linq query on c# objects :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
    objforOuterResource.InnerResources.Where(x => x.Id == 5);
```

Comment: To be more precise, i want to query them using Elasticsearch query in nest, not linq query on c# objects :)

Answer (score -1):

```
.Query<OuterResource>.Nested(n => n
    .Path(p => p.InnerResources)
    .Query(qq => qq
    .Terms(t => t.Fields(fi => fi.InnerResources.First().OuterResourceId ).Terms(value))
    )
)
```

Should work. Note the .First is applied to all the array (=list)